# What is the difference between the iPad Mini model numbers A1454 and A1455?

Tags: cellular-carriers, cellular-data, ipad

Apple lists the iPad mini models on the [Identifying iPad models](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5452) web page and lists two cellular models:

- A1454 on the iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular
- A1455 on the iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM)

I can't seem to find a mapping between these models and the iPads for sale by Apple since they list the intended carrier and a different part number like MD534LL/A. Apple has a nice [LTE page for iPhones](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/), but I can't find the iPad page.

In the US, the Black 16 GB iPad Mini (2012) has the following parts for our three cellular carriers:

- AT&T - MD534LL/A
- Sprint - ME215LL/A
- Verizon - MD540LL/A

None of the [Apple LTE articles](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1976) seem to be updated yet for the 4th Generation [iPad with LTE](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5205) or the iPad Mini with LTE so I'm stumped at the moment. What is the [difference between](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5452#ipad_mini) the **Cellular A1454** model and the **Cellular (MM) A1455** model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparable page you're looking for is: http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/. A1454 is used for AT&T and similar Canadian networks only, while Sprint, Verizon and overseas carriers use A1455.

All bands are also listed on [the specs page](http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/):

- Model A1454

  - GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
  - UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - LTE (Bands 4 and 17)
- Model A1455

  - CDMA EV-DO Rev. A and Rev. B (800, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
  - UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - LTE (Bands 1, 3, 5, 13, 25)

Comment: And I have absolutely no idea what MM stands for.

Comment: I'll see if I can get an answer on MM - thanks for the assist - it looks like you pressed "answer" about 50 seconds before I had my answer composed. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I just didn't look hard enough.

http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/ has all the goods on the model numbers.

The iPad mini **Cellular A1454** Model supports LTE bands 4 (AWS) and 17 (700b MHz). The carriers listed for this Model are AT&T in the US and all Canadian carriers (Bell, Rogers, Telus).

The iPad mini **Cellular A1455** Model supports LTE bands 1 (2100 MHz), 3 (1800 MHz), 5 (850 MHz), 13 (700c MHz), and 25 (1900 MHz). This model is for Sprint and Verizon in the US as well as all other countries around the globe.